# Cant Run Python Script From WebServer Using CGI

Tags: python, webserver, cgi

I've been able to run a script written with Perl and Bash on my Apache2.0 webserver, but I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I try doing the same with a python script.

I am using Ubuntu OS. 
The executable scripts are located in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`

I intentionally made my script very simple, and

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
print 'hello world'
```

I confirmed the Python interpreter is stored in `/usr/bin` as python3. I also tried changing the header as follows, but still got a 500 error

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I am at a loss for why this is the case, and the Internal 500 error isn't explanatory. Any suggestions?

Comment: `print 'hello world'` is invalid Python3 code (`print` is now a function). It should be `print('hello world')`. Does that stop the 500 error from happening?

Comment: Can you check if your file has read and execute permission for all, not only local user?  If not use set them, but let write permission active only for creator of the file that are you.

Comment: the parenthesis dont solve the issue. I copied the syntax from some examples online. @lulian could you elaborate? I did use `chmod +x` for all the scripts, so not sure why python would be the only one without permission

Comment: Oh right than let's try with some debugging. In python there is a module called `cgitb` that stay for _**CGI Traceback**_ to retrieve some information of the execution. By importing it and calling its **enable** function, you will get a helpful web page with more information on what went wrong than only "internal 500 error". So add `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()` after the pound bang line and see what you get when accessing the page from the browser.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still getting a 500 error with cgitb

Comment: `
import cgitb;
cgitb.enable();
#!/usr/bin/python3.6`

Comment: ok, checked the errors logs and am seeing this: ` End of script output before headers: testpython` how is this possible if headers are on the first line?

Comment: You are right @RandomDavis I realized this was part of the problem. Thank you, I am no longer getting the 500 error. If you post I will accept your answer